# How do I pass two parameters to GraphQLHttpClient in c#?

Tags: c#, graphql

I am having a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492576/graphqlclient-error-when-creating-an-graphqlhttpclient-igraphqlwebsocketjsonser). I have updated my GraphQLHttpClient and now I need to supply an extra parameter, solution give is:

```
GraphQLHttpClient gql = new GraphQLHttpClient(o => {
o.EndPoint = _config["API:Endpoint"];
o.JsonSerializer = new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
});
```

but this tells me:
`Error  CS1729  'GraphQLHttpClient' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`
I have also tried:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
GraphQLHttpClient gql = new GraphQLHttpClient(_options.Url, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer());
```

which gives `Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer' to 'GraphQL.Client.Abstractions.Websocket.IGraphQLWebsocketJsonSerializer'`

I know very little c# so I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first solution correctly tries to use `NewtonsoftJsonSerializer` which is an implementation of `IGraphQLWebsocketJsonSerializer` to use Newtonsoft.

Your second correctly uses a constructor which takes it, but you have changed it to be `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer` which is **not** an implementation of `IGraphQLWebsocketJsonSerializer`.

What you want is the second one, but with the right type of `IGraphQLWebsocketJsonSerializer`:

```
GraphQLHttpClient gql = new GraphQLHttpClient(_options.Url, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
```

Comment: Thank you, but that gives me `Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'NewtonsoftJsonSerializer' does not exist in the namespace` how do I get that one?

Comment: I had to get nuget package: `GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft`.

Comment: @schoon yep, I was just about to update this answer with exactly that. Well done!